# How can I calculate the Levenshtein distance between all rows in two dataframes and output the Levenshtein score for each pair?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to calculate the Levenshtein distance between two dataframes (dfa & dfb) as set out below.

dfa:

```
Name      Addresss     ID  
Name1a    Address1a    ID1a
Name2a    Address2a    ID2a
```

dfb:

```
Name      Addresss      ID  
Name1b    Address1b   ID1b
Name2b    Address2b   ID2b
```

I understand computing the distance between two strings but I am a bit confused as to how I could do a set of columns against another with the output looking something like this with it displaying all pairs and scores:

Output:

```
Name      Name      LevScore
Name1a    Name1b       0.87
Name1a    Name2b       0.45
Name1a    Name3b       0.26
Name2a    Name1b       0.92
Name2a    Name2b       0.67
Name2a    Name3b       0.56
etc
```

Thanks in advance!

Manesh

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you want calculate levScore?

Comment: Hi Narendra, I would like to calculate the Lev score between every 'Name' in dfa and every 'Name' in dfb and output the score for every pair along with a columns each for associated 'Name' values that were used to calculate the score. I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Do both your dataframes have identical indexes or an index column? Consider merging your dataframes first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the package `Levenshtein` together with `itertools` to get the combinations of values for the two columns :

```
import Levenshtein as lev
from itertools import product

new_df = pd.DataFrame(product(df1['Name'], df2['Name']), columns=["Name1","Name2"])

new_df["LevScore"] = new_df.apply(lambda x: lev.score(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)

print(new_df)

    Name1   Name2   LevScore
0   Name1a  Name1b  1
1   Name1a  Name2b  2
2   Name2a  Name1b  2
3   Name2a  Name2b  1
```

**EDIT**

Let's say this is your df1:

```
df1_n = pd.concat([df1,df1,df1]).reset_index(drop=True)
df1_n

Name    Addresss    ID
0   Name1a  Address1a   ID1a
1   Name2a  Address2a   ID2a
2   Name1a  Address1a   ID1a
3   Name2a  Address2a   ID2a
4   Name1a  Address1a   ID1a
5   Name2a  Address2a   ID2a
```

As you said you can compute the combinations of values taking chunks of size `step` from `df1_n`:

```
fina_df = pd.DataFrame()
step=2
for i in range(0,df1_n.shape[0],step):
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(product(df1_n.iloc[i:i+step,0], df2['Name']), columns=["Name1","Name2"])
    new_df["LevScore"] = new_df.apply(lambda x: lev.distance(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)
    fina_df = pd.concat([fina_df, new_df], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)

print(final_df)
```

Output:

```
Name1   Name2   LevScore
0   Name1a  Name1b  1
1   Name1a  Name2b  2
2   Name2a  Name1b  2
3   Name2a  Name2b  1
4   Name1a  Name1b  1
5   Name1a  Name2b  2
6   Name2a  Name1b  2
7   Name2a  Name2b  1
8   Name1a  Name1b  1
9   Name1a  Name2b  2
10  Name2a  Name1b  2
11  Name2a  Name2b  1
```

For your situation change 2 to 300 or 500. This should avoid to fill up your entire RAM, let me know if it works!

Comment: Hi there, your solution seems like it should fit for me but unfortunately everyone I run it my entire PC freezes up and I need to do a hard reset. Original file size was ~8500 rows each, I have lowered to 3000, 1000 and now just 10 but unfortunately getting the same freezing upon running the code. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: So even if you have 10 rows for each dataframe it does not work? really weird! that should generate a dataframe with 100 rows only.

Comment: Yep, even with just 10 rows my entire machine seizes up. For clarity this is the exact code I am using: new_df = pd.DataFrame(product(df1['CompanyA'], df2['CompanyB']), columns=["CompanyA","CompanyB"])  Maybe I'm making a tiny error there that I am overlooking. Or are there any alternate methods that can replicate the product function I could try?

Comment: The code seems fine to me. I don't understand why the machine stops working. So the problem is when you create the `new_df` or after ( in  `new_df.apply`)?

Comment: I have figured out why it freezes up on 10 rows, NaN rows weren't being dropped properly so there were still a bunch there getting in the way, I now have this working with 10 rows. Is there anyway I can loop through, say the first 500 or so in dfa compared to all of dfb then the next 500 etc? Not ideal but it could be workable.

Comment: Forgot to add that the problem occurs on creation of new_df

Comment: Absolutely amazing! I've run this on a sample of ~1000 and it gets done in ~25 seconds. Just to check this is what I have put into my code, is this the correct implementation:                                            fina_df = pd.DataFrame()
step=2
for i in range(0,df1.shape[0],step):
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(product(df1.iloc[i:i+step,0], df2['CompanyB']), columns=["CompanyA","CompanyB"])
    new_df["LevScore"] = new_df.apply(lambda x: lev.ratio(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)
    fina_df = pd.concat([fina_df, new_df], axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: Yes your code seems right to me! be sure that in `df1` the first column is the one named `"CompanyA"`. Thank you for accepting my answer!

Comment: Thanks to you also, yourself and Nicholas have gone above and beyond to help me out!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from textdistance import levenshtein
from itertools import product

# dfa = pd.read_clipboard()  # this is just to reproduce your dataframe

# dfb = pd.read_clipboard()  # this is just to reproduce your dataframe

dfc = pd.DataFrame(product(dfa['Name'], dfb['Name']), columns=['Name1', 'Name2'])

dfc['Distance'] = dfc.apply(lambda x: levenshtein.distance(x['Name1'],
                                                           x['Name2']), axis=1)
```

```
    Name1   Name2  Distance
0  Name1a  Name1b         1
1  Name1a  Name2b         2
2  Name2a  Name1b         2
3  Name2a  Name2b         1
```

Comment: I will remove my answer since we got the same result at the same time :D

Comment: That's really good sportsmanship but you can let OP decide our fate :)

Comment: Hi there, your solution seems like it should fit for me but unfortunately everyone I run it my entire PC freezes up and I need to do a hard reset. Original file size was ~8500 rows each, I have lowered to 3000, 1000 and now just 10 but unfortunately getting the same freezing upon running the code. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: You're looking for all possible permutations between two columns, so if they have 8,000 values each, it's 8,000*8,000 combinations: 64,000,000 calculations of distance. I don't know why you would be getting this problem with 10 rows though...

Comment: I have figured out why it freezes up on 10 rows, NaN rows weren't being dropped properly so there were still a bunch there getting in the way, I now have this working with 10 rows. Is there anyway I can loop through, say the first 500 or so in dfa compared to all of dfb then the next 500 etc? Not ideal but it could be workable.